# One Table, Several Views, one C# Class

Tags: c#, azure, windows-runtime, azure-mobile-services

I have a single c# class defined as

```
class HighScore
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "PlayerName")]
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "PlayerCountry")]
    public int PlayerCountry { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "PlayerTime")]
    public double PlayerTime { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "PlayerBadge")]
    public int PlayerBadge { get; set; }
}
```

And a table in my Azure mobile services SQL database that contains several records of this type. I have a number of views

```
select * from tellingthetime.HighScore where PlayerBadge=0
```

where the PlayerBadge is a number from 0 to 4. I also have a number of read scripts added to my Mobile Service that query the view and return the appropriate rows.

```
function read(query, user, request) {
    mssql.query("select * from OneStarBadgeLeaderBoard", {
        success: function(results) {
            console.log(results);
            request.respond(statusCodes.OK, results);
        }
    });   
}
```

The above script is called OneStarBadgeLeaderBoard, but my class is called HighScore. The code below I call to Get the underlying table.

```
private IMobileServiceTable<HighScore> HighScoreTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<HighScore>();
```

Without creating a different class name, the defintions are all the same as the SQL returned data is the same, for each read script, how do I make this work so I can call any read script, which queries the appropriate view to retrieve the values I need?

Hope that make sense.

Many thanks,

Jason.

P.S. Of course, I could read the entire table and query it with LINQ on the client, but that will increase the amount of data to download.

Comment: What language is your mobile service? Is it supposed to use the c# class?

Comment: Nick, it's using the Azure Mobile Services solution. My client is C#. The scripting on Azure is JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this from Josh Twist

```
function read(query, user, request) {

    var dispatch = {
        op1 : operation1,
        op2 : operation2,
    }

    if (request.parameters.operation && dispatch.hasOwnProperty(request.parameters.operation)) {
        dispatch[request.parameters.operation](query, user, request);
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
        // default path for execution
        request.execute();
    }
}

function operation1(query, user, request) {
    request.respond(200, "this result is from operation1");
}

function operation2(query, user, request) {
    request.respond(200, "this result is from operation2");
}
```

http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Dispatching_to_different_query_functions_in_Mobile_Services.aspx

Also this code sends a filtered OData request that only retrieves the required records. Got it from the ToDo list Azure Mobile Service Tutorials

```
private async void RefreshTodoItems()
{
            // This code refreshes the entries in the list view by querying the TodoItems table.
            // The query excludes completed TodoItems
            var results = await todoTable
                .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Complete == false)
                .ToListAsync();

            items = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>(results);
            ListItems.ItemsSource = items;
}
```